# File not found exception 2

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

```
String filename = new String(APDirectory.META_DATA.getPath() + getDefaultFileName() + ".ini");
File iniFile = new File(filename);

try {
    Wini ini = new Wini(iniFile);
    ini.put(title, "Comment:", comment);
    ini.put(title, "Position:", rectangle.x + "," + rectangle.y + "," + rectangle.width + "," + rectangle.height);
    ini.store();
} catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

static String getDefaultFileName() {
    String output = new String(ImageInfo.imageName);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    output += "_" + dateFormat.format(new Date());

    return output;
}
```

I created a new file but I get the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\XXX\AP\MetaData\CB_2015-09-01_07-31-01.ini (Sistem belirtilen
>   dosyayı bulamıyor)    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)

Comment: Try printing `System.out.println(APDirectory.META_DATA.getPath() + getDefaultFileName() + ".ini");`

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava here is output : C:\Users\XXX\AP\MetaData\CB_2015-09-01_07-38-42.ini

Comment: We have no idea what `Wini` is and what `Wini` does. Also have you checked that the file actually exist?

Comment: Is that a valid directory on your computer? Have you tried to open it in your file manager?

Comment: @dotvav Wini is a ini library : ini4j-0.5.4.jar, i downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ini4j/files/

Comment: Yeah, try to put `C:\Users\XXX\AP\MetaData\CB_2015-09-01_07-38-42.ini` it in your windows address bar & check if it opens

Comment: @Craig C:\Users\XXX\AP\MetaData\ is exists but ini file does not exist. I want to create in this folder.

Comment: Are you running the java program with a windows account that is allowed to read/write in that directory?

Comment: @dotvav yes, i have all permissions

Comment: Wini ini = new Wini(iniFile); this line gives an error, because .ini file does not exist. But how can i create file ? File iniFile = new File(filename); -> does not create a file.

Comment: @Dauezevy try this `iniFile.createNewFile()`

Comment: @kucing_terbang, yes, i found before few seconds before :) thanks :)

Comment: This debug statement could help; System.out.printl( "ini location: " + iniFile.getAbsolutePath() + ", exists? "+ (ini.exists());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String filename = new String(APDirectory.META_DATA.getPath() + getDefaultFileName() + ".ini");
System.out.println(APDirectory.META_DATA.getPath() + getDefaultFileName() + ".ini");
File iniFile = new File(filename);

Wini ini;

try {
    iniFile.createNewFile();
    ini = new Wini(iniFile);
    ini.put(title, "Comment:", comment);
    ini.put(title, "Position:", rectangle.x + "," + rectangle.y + "," + rectangle.width + "," + rectangle.height);
    ini.store();
} catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I had to explicitly create the file using `iniFile.createNewFile();`

The Wini constructor does not do this automatically.